# Why in this tree program i am getting the output twice?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Can anyone explain why I am getting the output twice here?

```
# include<iostream>
# include<conio.h>
# include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct tree
{
  int data;
  struct tree * left;
  struct tree * right;
};

struct tree * insert(struct tree * root,int value)
{
   if (root==NULL)
   {
      struct tree * node= (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
      node->data=value;
      node->right=NULL;
      node->left=NULL;
      return node;
   }
   else if(root->data > value )
      root->left=insert(root->left,value);
   else
      root->right=insert(root->right,value);
}

int same_tree(struct tree * root1, struct tree* root2)
{
   if((root1==NULL && root2!=NULL) || (root1!=NULL && root2==NULL))
   {
      cout << " tree are not equal \n"; 
      return -1;
   }
   if(root1 && root2)
   {
      same_tree(root1->left,root2->left);
      if(root1->data!=root2->data)
      {
         cout << "tree not equal \n";   
         return -1;                        
      } 
      same_tree(root1->right,root2->right);
   }   
}

int main()
{
   struct tree * root=NULL;
   root= insert(root,8);
   insert(root,6);
   insert(root,7);
   insert(root,5);
   insert(root,1);
   insert(root,20);
   insert(root,15);
   struct tree * root2=NULL; 
   root2= insert(root2,8);
   insert(root2,6);
   insert(root2,7);
   insert(root2,5);
   insert(root2,1);
   insert(root2,20);
   insert(root2,18);
   int j= same_tree(root,root2);
   if(j==-1)
      cout << " tree not eqqual \n";
   else
      cout << "tree are equal\n";
   getch();
   return 0;   
}
```

The program is written to compare if two tree are same ( in the same hierarchial structure and data they contain) . The two tree i am comparing here is passed from main (root and root2). 
In case of equal tree i get the O/o as  "tree are equal" once . But in case tree are not equal i get an o/p "tre not equal " and in next line as "tree are equal " . I am unable to decipher Why ? I have written down the entire program so that anyone can copy paste and run it on their system . I guess The problem lies somewhere in recursive call of same_tree but where and why is something i am not getting

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: What *language* is this? FrankenC++?

Comment: @Luchian sorry mea culpa ... untagged it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing the trees you only return -1 (error) if the left node differs. You just ignore the right nodes. Also, if your trees only differ on the right side your same_tree does not return a value at all. I'm actually surprised this compiled at all.

If you look at your same_tree closely you will see that it checks if only one of the let/right is null and then if non are null. However, if they are both null you just fall through. You also ignore the return value at many points.

Say you have two roots, each with value 5 and one of them has left 7 while the other has left 8. Now when entering the same_tree you will compare the lefts which will front that that are different. However, the return value is ignored and you will continue with comparing the root value (both 5) and since they are same you will not return the error code and your main method will think every thing is fine and dandy and print that they are equal.

Comment: yeah thats true , may be what i have done is not a good programming practice . But i have made sure it returns -1 in case they are not equal . And made that check in main on that basis . But still i am not sure Why am i getting two O/P .

Comment: You should get two outputs when they are not equal, you have outputs both in your same_tree and in your main().

Comment: Thanks a lot .Voted and accepted your answer for finding the fault as you mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it bother you that you are missing return statement in same_tree for equal trees? Compiler should warn you about it. If you are using g++ you should always use

```
-W -Wall (-pedantic is good as well)
```

Comment: yeah thats true , may be what i have done is not a good programming practice . But i have made sure it returns -1 in case they are not equal . And made that check in main on that basis . But still i am not sure Why am i getting two O/P . Newaz  +1 for your suggestion

Comment: Because your function(same_tree) will always reach condition where it returns -1 (at some level of recursion). It will print "Trees not equal". Then execution will go up the stack and at the top there is no return statement so function returns some random value. (0 in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in your insert method (surprise it compiled):

```
struct tree * insert(struct tree * root,int value)
{
   if (root==NULL)
   {
      struct tree * node= (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
      node->data=value;
      node->right=NULL;
      node->left=NULL;
      return node;
   }
   else if(root->data > value )
      root->left=insert(root->left,value);
   else
      root->right=insert(root->right,value);

   return root;
}
```

Comment: thats certainly not the problem . The node to be inserted will always be returned from if(root==NULL), though i am not catching them except the first value which i want to be root. If you edit my program with your return statement it wont make any difference in the O/P Which i have mentioned

Comment: And also missed return value inside same_tree.

Comment: By not returning the `root` as I added, you are destroying any tree that has more than 3 nodes, as the left/right pointer of the original root node will be set to garbage (or NULL if your compiler is nice) on the 4th insertion. This then is why your trees evaluate as equal, because by the time you get to the `same_tree` method in your test code, you have destroyed your child nodes and are only left with the root nodes, which are equal in your test code.

Comment: @claireware What kind of compiler do you mean When you say compiler is nice ?

Comment: @Ritesh `root->left=insert(root->left,value);` the recursive calls to `insert` in middle (stack frame) won't return anything since in those `root` were not `null` , so `root->left` will have unspecified values , which means your tree is ill now.

Comment: Who downvoted you?, though it's not complete answer but got part of main issues.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I guess it was Mr.Stakx . I have enough courtsey not to downvote some one Who is actually taking the pain to see and reply to my qquestion